# How do I trim white space on Caucho Resin?

Tags: jsp, resin

I am trying to apply this directive to my server but I'm not sure where to add it:

```
<jsp-property-group>
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
   <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
</jsp-property-group>
```

I am using resin 4.0.35 pro.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the `jsp-property-group` is a child of `jsp-config`, and `jsp-config` a child of `web-app`. Put it in your `web.xml` or `resin-web.xml`

Comment: So I did this on our main xml file but it didn't seem to help. `<web-app-default>
   <jsp>
    <auto-compile>true</auto-compile>
    <dependency-check-interval>60s</dependency-check-interval>
   </jsp>
   <jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
     <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
   </jsp-config>
  </web-app-default>`